# Disable auto-close application Android

Tags: android, memory

When Android (version 2.3) has too little memory off the application. I did a test on a device with a free 140 mb of memory when I turned on the browser and opened four cards have 30-40MB free. My application is 10 MB, but if you start to use the other to Android itself it off. Is it possible to force Android to never turn off the application? This is so annoying that I have in this application and session variables (ApplicationState) after returning begin to happen strange things.

Answer (score 3):

It is only possible to fully prevent this by modifying the android system itself (ie, rebuild, or at minimum rooting).  Even then, at a certain point of memory pressure, preventing your app from being killed translates to crashing whatever the user was trying to do in the foreground, or even the device in general.

You are better off properly handling the possibility of being killed, in accordance with the activity lifecycle, as others have already recommended.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is "This is not possible".  You could try using foreground service [here is a sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/ForegroundService.html) but even then you are not guaranteed that your app won't be killed.  If android really does need memory for more important apps, e.g. telephony.

Rather than trying to do what you're describing, I suggest you actually carefully review [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) and implement proper callbacks to save and restore your session/state.

Comment: Wow that is completely unacceptable. Apparently Google introduced this "feature" in 2.2, as before that apps would not get killed for no good reason just because you switched to another app (for instance, to get a piece of info you needed for the app you are on), forcing in many cases the need to re-login.

Comment: Also, this behavior completely wrecks the behavior of MANY apps I have no control over - the web browser, youtube, vnc viewer, my online banking apps, etc.  I am sick and tired of Android killing my apps just because it feels like it.  It is wrong and Google should be derided for this poor decision.  The comments directed at Google, not you btw - just venting as I have no control over Google nor any way to fix it.

Comment: @Michael I agree that this is not the most desirable of behaviour, however it is necessary to maintain the stability of the system.  It was not introduced in 2.2 - it's always been there. It's present in my old 2.1 phone and it's also easy to see in 1.6 emulator.

Comment: Hmm.  Well I have been search and searching for a way around this.  My phone is almost unusable for my purposes if I run the risk of losing my place in an app every time I momentarily switch away from it or turn off the phone.  Thanks for the reply, I won't go the route of trying to see what changed from 2.1 to 2.2 and fork my own android (like I had time to do that anyway :-)

Comment: @AleksG The activity lifecycle does not handle the problem at all. Sometimes there are apps which MUST NOT be closed because they need to perform tasks continuously and must not be interrupted. Especially logging apps, like a GPS tracker, sensor loggers, etc. Android's need for an activity lifecycle is understandable, but it is not understandable why they didn't offer a way to disable auto closing for certain apps. This would not break the system, since most apps can live without it.

Answer (score 1):

No it isn't possible. The best you can do is use a foreground service, but even that doesn't guarantee your app won't be killed.

It sounds though like you might really want to just store the state of the app so that when you restart it's in the same state the user left it in.  If you properly store and restore the application state you shouldn't get strange things happening.

Do you understand the Activity lifecycle?  If not, I suggest you read up on it.